# Have trouble with making div stay at bottom of div

Tags: jquery, css, html

Sample code

```
<section id="loadGallery" style="overflow:hidden;">

<?php foreach ($this->imgs as $p)  
{ ?>
<article>
<a href="<?= $C->SITE_URL ?>pics/<?= $p->pic_id ?>">
<img src="/uploads/<?= $p->img ?>"/>
</a>
</article>
<?php }?>

<div class="more" id="<?= $p->pic_id ?>">load more</div>

</section>
```

The articles have **float:left** and the images **height:150px**

First I load **11** imgs and when the **.more** is click get that last id and load more imgs.Removes the **.more** div and then change it with the new **.more** div

Currently when the ajax is successful i'm using **$('#loadGallery').append(e);**

The problem is that the **.more** div is not bellow the images instead is next to the last img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.more { clear: both; }` should do the trick. I wouldn't recommend using empty markup for clearing/styling purposes

Comment: Yes that work but now the .more is to close to the image and using **margin-top** dosent do anything..

Comment: adding a padding-top does the job?

Answer (score 1):

you shuld add an element that clears the float so that the float is reset

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: Yes that work but now the .more is to close to the image and using **margin-top** dosent do anything..